# JasperReports: Stretch behavior for lists

Tags: jasper-reports

I use the *List* component in my report, and after/underneath the *List* there are further report elements following.

The *List*'s underlying collection can contain between 1 and 50 records, so I don't know at report design time how large the list will become, so I don't know where exactly to place these following elements.

I am looking for a way to make the list stretch properly just as a *textField*, but the **isStretchWithOverflow** attribute is defined only for *textFields*, not for the *List*.
Currently for larger *Lists* the *List* overlaps with the following report elements.

Does anyone know what is the intended stretching behavior of *Lists* or how I could solve my problem?

P.S. I crossposted this question already at the [JasperReports forum](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=92300) but no answer :(

Here is a code example:

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="200">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="500" height="100" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"/>
            <c:list xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="airfreightRates">
                    <dataSourceExpression>$F{spotAirfreightRates}</dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>

                <c:listContents height="35">
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="15"/>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                            "This is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long textFieldExpression"
                        </textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </c:listContents>
            </c:list>
        </componentElement>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="500" height="50" positionType="Float" />
            <textElement isStyledText="true"/>
            <text><![CDATA[<font color="#FF0000">Static text outside the list contents!!<b>The placement of the text is the crucial point!!!</b></font>]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Eventually, we abandoned the idea of using JR and shipping iReport to the customer and implemented our own designer suiting to our needs

Answer (score 0):

Try to set properties like in this sample:

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="186" y="0" width="57" height="20"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
                    <datasetParameter name="parameter1">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="20" width="57">
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="41" height="10"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf($F{POSITIONS_POSITIONNO}).concat("LONG STRING, very long string ")]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODUCT_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

I've set ***`RelativeToTallestObject`*** property for `List`, `TextField in List` and `external TextField` and set ***`isStretchWithOverflow`*** for `external TextField`.

Comment: It worked for me in a similar way now. 

In every textField contained in the list I set isStretchWithOverflow="true".
On the elements that follow the table I set positionType="Float" so they float accordingly to the additional space the list requires.

I was quite sure that I exactly tried that out before, but probably I did something wrong…

Comment: Alex's solution does not work for me - my next element is a subreport, setting that to Float makes it disappear :-( Any ideas on how to solve this in a nicer way?

Comment: All I had to do was set the external TextFields (following the table) to use positionType="Float".

Comment: @DaDaDom: perhaps the subreport disappears because it no longer has enough space to appear in the band? Try increasing the band height.

Answer (score 0):

Please try put the list in the background.

```
<background>
    <band height="842" splitType="Prevent">
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="9020735c-7a94-4807-9596-1aabac997a00" x="28" y="492" width="290" height="14"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="4259289c-8858-4336-a37b-8ad5a7a1ba51" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="290" height="14"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="bf8de899-aa0b-43b4-9f4d-1e999524f66d">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{inclusions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="14" width="290">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="f8997d71-b315-4be6-9bdf-c3d0c20d0424" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="14" y="3" width="271" height="8" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#4A4A49"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="Avenir-Medium" size="11" isBold="false"/>
                                <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" lineSpacingSize="1.03"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{inclusion}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </frame>
    </band>
```